# Calculate $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0, 1]} f_m(x) d\lambda(x)$.

Tags: lebesgue-integral

> Let $p \in (0, \infty)$ and the sequence of functions $f_m : [0, 1] \rightarrow \Bbb R, m \in \Bbb N$,
>
> $f_m(x) := ((1 - x^p)^{1 \over p})^m$.
>
> Calculate
>
> $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0, 1]} f_m(x) d\lambda(x)$.

How would I start approaching this problem? I remember that there is a theorem that allows me to change the limes and the integral under certain conditions, but it's been a while since I used it. Should I start with this?

Comment: dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: The theorem you are talking about is propably the Dominated Convergence Theorem of Lebesgue. Search it on wiki. Here the functions are continuous on the closed interval $[0,1]$ and therefore bounded. Moreover the measure of the interval (length in the case of intervals) is finite. Thus the functions are dominated. So you can apply the theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_m$ is dominated by the integrable function $1$. Since $(1-x^p)^{1/p}<1$ for almost every $x$ in the interval, raising it to the $m$th power makes it closer and closer to $0$ as $m$ increases. Then the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) gives $\int_{[0,1]} 0 \, d\lambda = 0$ as the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! In order to apply the theorem, I would also have to show that the sequence of the functions is indeed integrable, right?

Comment: Yes. It is enough to show it's continuous in this case.

Comment: Isn't it just continuous as a composition of continuous functions?

Comment: Or: Isn't it integrable because it is bounded on $[0, 1]$?

Comment: Boundedness isn't good enough (Vitali sets show this), but yes, it's a composition of continuous functions, so it is cts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort!